# How to refresh kerberos ticket in running structured streaming spark application once in 7 days?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, kerberos, spark-structured-streaming

I've been running a structured streaming application to join 2 streams from kafka and push to the third stream. The application gets failed once in 7 days as `HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN` expires. I'm using jaas file to send the relevant configuration.

```
RegistryClient {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    useKeyTab=true
    keyTab="./user.keytab"
    storeKey=true
    useTicketCache=false
    principal="uder@Principal";
};
```

Comment: Maybe try using k5start? https://linux.die.net/man/1/k5start

Comment: Thank you. We achieved it by refreshing Kerberos in one of the nodes and passing this config as a part of spark-submit command.

Comment: Have you checked Kerberos Protocol transition and Constrained delegation? You won't need user's ticket in such case, service user can impersonate the user internally.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the below parameters in spark submit command.

--conf spark.yarn.keytab=/path/to/file.keytab
--conf spark.yarn.principal=principleName@domain